# How to make selected value in single select grow similar to multi select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

In react select, if I am using multi select, all the selected values appear as pills and the whole input box grows to show all the selected values. But in case of single select, it just remains fixed and any overflowing text is cut off by ellipsis. There are scenarios where the single select will have restricted width on UI, but I can have scope in height to adjust so that user can see the entire selected option. It that possible with CSS changes? Or there is any config for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create your own `Select` element with a custom `styles` props like this:

```
const styles = {
  singleValue: base => ({
    ...base,
    // You will to add a bit more space around your option so it can fit
    maxWidth: "calc(100% - 10px)",
    position: "relative",
    textOverflow: "initial",
    top: "initial",
    transform: "none",
    whiteSpace: "initial"
  })
};

<Select options={options} styles={styles} />
```

One important point is to reset the positionnement `absolute` of the element.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/40y7nnokr0).